# Monitor getting weird after a while

Tags: 12.04, dell, monitor

I got this problem I've been trying to solve for a while now. 
If I leave my computer unattended for maybe half an hour my monitor turns black and pops an errorbox complaining that my resolution is wrong (wich it isn't). I've tried and turn off screenlock, screensaver and just about anything I could think off but nothing has helped? My monitor is a Samsung SyncMaster 912N and my computer is a Dell Optiplex 170L. I've attached my graphics specs. 
Does anyone know how to fix this it would be greatly appreaciated!

/Alex

!(http://ubuntu.se/attachment.php?attachmentid=5134&d=1351805185)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried reinstalling your monitor driver?

**OR**

your monitor itself has its own power save options! Check just to be sure...

Oh! I just found something that may solve your problem...

1) Open the 'Ubuntu Software Center' 
2) Then type in 'ARandR'... find it and install it

**Fingers crossed :)**

Comment: Yeah, tried to reinstall the drivers and It doesnt seem like the monitor has any powersaving. The really crappy thing is that when I turn my monitor of and on again it's still the same black screen with the errorbox. I have to turn my hole system down for at least 30 minutes to get it working again. Really frustrating...

Comment: I just found a good app for Linux...

1) Open the 'Ubuntu Software Center'

2) Then type in 'ARandR'... find it and install it

Fingers crossed :)

Comment: Cool, will try =)

Comment: Hey can you vote for my answer and tick it??? Thanks

Comment: Yeah, just gotta get some more rep before I can vote!

Comment: Ah sorry forgot about that :)